# Why there are so many way to set CSS for Widgets in GWT or GWTP, I am confused? Can someone clarify this?

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwtp, cssresource

Ok, to set a Css for a widget in Gwt or Gwtp, we can do following:

```
-1. directly from gwt code. Ex: label1.getElement().getStyle().setBackground("blue");
-2. include "ui:style" in UiBinder xml file, but this css only visible to that UiBinder
-3. include "ui:width" in UiBinder xml file, it will visible to all UiBinder
 - and there r many way to set the Css directly to the widget in UiBinder.
```

The one that made me confused is that if i used , ex

```
<ui:with field='res' type="com.myproj.client.MyResource" />
```

& if `myResource.css` has `.gwt-TabLayoutPanel` then i don't need to use "addStyleNames", ex `<g:TabLayputPanel />`, it can recognized CSS perfectly.

However, if i add `.gwt-ScrollPanel` into `myResource.css` & use `<g: ScrollPanel />` then nothing happened.

So I have to create `public interface MyCssResource extends CssResource`, then add `String gwt-ScrollPanel();` to `MyCssResource`. But Java eclipse do not allow hyphen `-` in the method name, so I have to change to `String gwtScrollPanel();`.

Finally, i have to add `addStyleNames` into `<g: ScrollPanel />`, ex `<g: ScrollPanel addStyleNames="{res.css.gwtScrollPanel}" />` then it will work.

That also means if i want to use `.gwt-TabLayoutPanel` in `MyCssResource`, then i need to remove the hyphen `-` & this will cause inconsistency in my code.

So, can someone explain to me what is going on here? I am confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you create a TabLayoutPanel, it has a default class called .gwt-TabLayoutPanel. So you don't need to add that class manually in to your TabLayoutPanel.Just create a TabLayoutPanel and you will see the class ".gwt-TabLayoutPanel" is already there.

[image]

But ScrollPanel doesn't comes with a default class called .gwt-ScrollPanel. It is just a div. Try creating a ScrollPanel and see. It doesn't have any classes added initially.see the screenshot

[image]

If you want to add a class called .gwt-ScrollPanel you will have to do it manually.

Comment: Thax u very much for ur instruction. I am clear now. But why Goole doesn't make ".gwtTabLayoutPanel" as default? so that i can use it in MyCssResource.java ? Instead they used ".gwt-TabLayoutPanel " & then i can't use ".gwt-TabLayoutPanel" in MyCssResource.java cos of hyphen.

Answer (score 2):

The only think you should be aware about, is that GWT obfuscates class names when you use then in ui-binders. For instance:

```
 <ui:style>
   .gwtTabLayoutPanel {}
 </ui:style>
 <g:TabLayoutPanel addStyleNames="{style.gwtTabLayoutPanel}" />
```

`.gwtTabLayoutPanel` will be renamed to something like `.AB` in the final injected style-sheet.

But most GWT widgets, are styled with un-obfuscated class names, so for using them in ui-binders files, you have to define as external in order to prevent GWT compier to obfuscate the class name:

```
 <ui:style>
   @external .gwt-TabLayoutPanel;
   .gwt-TabLayoutPanel {}
 </ui:style>
 <g:TabLayoutPanel />
```